# How to get model data on view in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, view, model, handlebars.js

How can i access model data in my view template in Ember JS ?
Is it saved in a global variable?

Here's my template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todo-list">
    {{#if length}}
    <section id="main">
        {{#if canToggle}}
        {{input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all" checked=allTodos.allAreDone}}
        {{/if}}
        <ul id="todo-list">
            {{#each}}
            <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed isEditing:editing"}}>
                {{#if isEditing}}
                {{todo-input type="text" class="edit" value=bufferedTitle focus-out="doneEditing" insert-newline="doneEditing" escape-press="cancelEditing"}}
                {{else}}
                {{input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked=isCompleted}}
                <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{title}}</label>
                <button {{action "removeTodo"}} class="destroy"></button>
                {{/if}}
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </section>
    {{/if}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
    <section id="todoapp">
        <header id="header">
            <h1>todos</h1>
            {{todo-input id="new-todo" type="text" value=newTitle action="createTodo" placeholder="What needs to be done?"}}
        </header>
        {{outlet}}
        {{#if length}}
        <footer id="footer">
            <span id="todo-count"><strong>{{remaining.length}}</strong> {{pluralize 'item' remaining.length}} left</span>
            <ul id="filters">
                <li>
                    {{#link-to "todos.index" activeClass="selected"}}All{{/link-to}}
                </li>
                <li>
                    {{#link-to "todos.active" activeClass="selected"}}Active{{/link-to}}
                </li>
                <li>
                    {{#link-to "todos.completed" activeClass="selected"}}Completed{{/link-to}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            {{#if completed.length}}
            <button id="clear-completed" {{action "clearCompleted"}}>Clear completed</button>
            {{/if}}
        </footer>
        {{/if}}
    </section>
    <footer id="info">
        <p>Double-click to edit a todo</p>
    </footer>
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `Route` sets up a "model" variable that is accessible by your template via:

- `{{model.myProperty}}` or
- `{{myProperty}}` (Before Ember2 this way would look up into your Controller Computed Properties. If none exists, then it would proxy through `model.myProperty`. [See this deprecation](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller))

In order to make the model data accessible "outisde of Ember" your can:

1. Create a Component
2. From the template, call it and pass the data down to it
3. Use `onDidInsertElement` and read the property. From now on, you can make it accessible to "the outisde world"

*OBS: I'm not sure that's a good practice though.*

JS BIN: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dapidu/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how can i store it in a javascript variable in order to work with in another js script in the same html page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in a different template (which is linked to a different controller I guess?), you can create an alias in the other controller like this :

```
//Include the first controller
needs: ['todoController'],
length: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.todoController.length'),
```

I don't have much precisions on how you built your application, but if you can't access it from the other template, it means your changing the application context (firstController -> secondController).

Do you have 2 controllers?